# How to remove nested collection when destroying model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

I'm initializing nested collection like te following:

```
var post = {
  id: 123,
  title: 'Sterling Archer',    
  comments: [
    {text: 'Comment text', tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']},
    {text: 'Comment test', tags: ['tag2', 'tag5']}
  ]  
};

var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function (response) {
       if (response.comments) {
          response.comments = new Backbone.Collection(response.comments);
       }
       return response;
   }
});

var post = new PostModel(post, {parse: true});
```

How should I remove nested 'comments' collection when removing model?

```
post.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `destroy` method of your `PostModel` instead of `sync` (which will not be called in case of a new model without `id` attribute):

```
destroy: function(options) {
    this.get('comments').each(function(mdl) {
         mdl.destroy();
    });

   Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, options)
}
```

Comment: Does this.get('comments') have .destroy() method as commentator above suggested?

Comment: `Backbone.Collection` has no default `destroy` method

Answer (score -1):

This something can be use to delete comments.

```
sync : function(method,model,options){
   if(method=='delete'){
       this.comments.destroy();
   }
   Backbone.sync(method,model,options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this.comments.destroy(); could be async.